# Limit number of connections pulled

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm on a  MEAN stack using passportjs and linkedin-passport to retrieve authorize users and retrieve information. However, I want to the limit the number of connections that a user has to 100. Is this possible and if so how do I specify this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous.  It reads like you want to limit the -total- number of connections a user can ever have, which is not possible via the API.

However, what I really think you mean is how to limit the number of connection results returned from an API request, in which case, the documentation on LinkedIn's developer site is quite clear about this:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

There are *start* and *count* parameters you can include in your query for paging through result sets.